# ASP MVC EF6 Access foreign key table as list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have 2 tables, codes and countries, with a foreign key constraint on codes.countryid on countries.id - I am using the basic crud given by the controller mvc setup from within visual studio 15 but would like to replace the text input with a select for countryid so that the user can select a country from a dropdown as appose to entering the id as an int.

How do I access a list of the countries through the provided Model? Sample razor code below. Do I need to get the countries list from another model?

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="CountryId" class="control-label col-md-2">Country</label>
            <select name="CountryId" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="">Please select ...</option>
 /* Model.Countries is not available even after a foreignkey constraint? */
                @foreach(var i in Model.Countries)
                {
                    <option value="@i.id">@i.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a `ViewBag` variable in the controller action with the list of countries.

Assuming you have a DB Context inside your controller, you should put the following code in your action

```
ViewBag.CountriesList = new SelectList(_context.countries.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
```

And use it as below inside your view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.countryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CountriesList , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```